Sum of independent random variables question
In the problem below, what language gives away that we need to create 2 separate integrals to calculate the exact probability? Why can we not just do a double integral \begin{equation} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{a-y}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy \end{equation}


What exactly does your double-integral try to represent? Is $f(x, y)$ the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$?
On the other hand, I believe that doing two integrals separately just make it clearer, as I don't see where you're going with your double-integral at the first glance.

The double integral appears to be the cumulative distribution function $F_{X+Y}(a) = \mathsf P(X+Y\leqslant a)$.  However, you wish to find the probability density function.

The finite support of $X$ and $Y$ is an indication that one must carefully consider what happens when the interval of integration lies outside the support.  Specifically, if you simply wrote
$$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^{a-y} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy,$$ without regard to what this quantity represents, what happens if $a-y > 1$, or $a-y < 0$?  Either case could occur and you cannot just integrate without taking this into account.
But you have an even more basic problem, which is that you haven't thought about what this double integral is supposed to represent even when $0 \le a-y \le 1$.  If we assume this condition is satisfied, then your integral literally means
$$\Pr[(0 \le Y \le 1) \cap (0 \le X \le a - Y)].$$
If we take for granted that each of $X$ and $Y$ is limited to $[0,1]$, we can simplify the joint inequality as
$$X+Y \le a,$$
which corresponds to the cumulative distribution of $X+Y$, not the density of $X+Y$.  So you would need to calculate a derivative to recover the density after your double integration, which of course is extra work that you could have avoided by not doing a double integral in the first place.

I did plan on finding the derivative after finding the cumulative distribution. The explanation that you gave makes sense as to my "more basic problem" that I did not account for. I am still confused as to how they jump from the equation following "We obtain" to the equation(s) afterwards. How do we know a is supposed to be in the upper limit for that first integral and why do we know we have to break them up?

@Mitchell I'm a big fan of thinking geometrically. Imagine $X, Y$ being plotted on a Cartesian coordinate plane; then $(X,Y)$ is located in the unit square.  So if $X+Y = a$ is a fixed constant, this corresponds to a diagonal line passing through the points $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$. You can see that as $a$ changes from $0$ to $2$, that this diagonal line intersects the bottom and left sides of the square for $0 \le a < 1$, but when $a = 1$ it passes through the corners. Then when $1 < a \le 2$, it passes through the right and upper sides of the square. So this tells us we need separate cases.

The advantage of this approach is that it extends to the more general case when $X \in [p,q]$ and $Y \in [r,s]$, and for any linear combination $\alpha X + \beta Y$.  You'd draw the rectangle with vertices $(p,r), (q,r), (q,s), (p,s)$, and consider lines through this rectangle where $\alpha X + \beta Y$ is constant.  Whenever this line intersects a vertex of the rectangle is where you must split the computation into a separate case.

If you rewrite the densities with an indicator random variable to avoid piecewise definitions as $$f_X(a)=f_Y(a)= 1_{[0\le a \le 1]}$$
then you can say $$f_{X+Y}(a) = \int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(a-y)\,dy= \int\limits_{\max(0,a-1)}^{\min(1,a)} 1 \,dy$$ so when you calculate this, the pieces come back and you in effect need to consider each of the cases $0<a<1$  and $1<a<2$ separately, getting $a$ and $2-a$ respectively.
Your double integral is for the CDF $P(X+Y \le a)$ and for $a\ge 0$ would look like $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a-y}f_X(x)f_Y(y) \,dx\,dy = \int\limits_{0}^{\min(1,a)} \int\limits_{0}^{\min(1,a-y)} 1 \,dx\,dy  $$ and again you are going to have to deal with the different cases.
